# How to add a custom view to Picker or Menu on macOS SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, menu, picker

I'm looking for a way to add views to Picker and Menu in SwiftUI. MacOS automatically apply default style to Picker/Menu and ignore everything else. How does it possible to achieve this results? Thanks.

[image: picker example]

Possible usecases for this picker:

- to display colors previews
- to add additional information
- to display images

Comment: Use AppKit directly

Comment: @Roman Banks, have you found any way to achieve this in SwiftUI ?

Comment: @KrishnaMaru I decided to fake native menu inside SwifUI Popover for the moment. Hope Apple will introduce a proper api for menus at WWDC 23

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TqEG3bAaeg) could be a point to start